# get Margins from a div javascript

Tags: javascript, css, margin

I need to change the margins of a div through javascript. But there is no such way as:

```
document.getElementById('div').style.margin-top = var;
```

Is there a way to do this? I can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `marginTop`, not `margin-top`

```
document.getElementById('AnIdNotADiv').style.marginTop = value + "px";
```

Comment: Aah thank you, lol, and i know it is an ID, i just mistyped, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the functionality you're looking for, it can manipulate elements that don't have IDs.  Once the jQuery Library is included, the syntax for what you want would be:

$('div').css('margin-top',var);

For information about including jQuery, visit the jQuery API site:
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Setup

Comment: No, my elements have ID´s now, i fixed it, but thanks, because i didn´t knew that jQuery trick either